# valgrind error with __builtin_ctz

Tags: c++, ubuntu-12.04, valgrind

I'm trying to profile my code but run into problems.

If I run the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    size_t val = 8;

    std::cout << sizeof(val) << std::endl;
    std::cout << __builtin_ctz(val) << std::endl;
}
```

It returns as expected

```
8
3
```

If I run valgrind on it it returns:

```
==28602== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==28602== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==28602== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==28602== Command: ./test
==28602== 
8
vex amd64->IR: unhandled instruction bytes: 0xF3 0xF 0xBC 0xC0 0x89 0xC6 0xBF 0x60
==28602== valgrind: Unrecognised instruction at address 0x400890.
==28602==    at 0x400890: main (in /home/magu_/sod/test/test)
==28602== Your program just tried to execute an instruction that Valgrind
==28602== did not recognise.  There are two possible reasons for this.
==28602== 1. Your program has a bug and erroneously jumped to a non-code
==28602==    location.  If you are running Memcheck and you just saw a
==28602==    warning about a bad jump, it's probably your program's fault.
==28602== 2. The instruction is legitimate but Valgrind doesn't handle it,
==28602==    i.e. it's Valgrind's fault.  If you think this is the case or
==28602==    you are not sure, please let us know and we'll try to fix it.
==28602== Either way, Valgrind will now raise a SIGILL signal which will
==28602== probably kill your program.
==28602== 
==28602== Process terminating with default action of signal 4 (SIGILL)
==28602==  Illegal opcode at address 0x400890
==28602==    at 0x400890: main (in /home/magu_/sod/test/test)
==28602== 
==28602== HEAP SUMMARY:
==28602==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28602==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==28602== 
==28602== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==28602== 
==28602== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==28602== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

Is this an bug of valgrind or should I not use `__builtin_ctz` with my computer? `__builtin_popcount` does not raise any errors.

My system:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04) 4.8.1
CPU : Intel Core Duo T7500
```

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour. Thank you for the tip. Wconversion doesn't show anything. I needed an explicit cast to unsinged int. With __builtin_ctzll this was not necessary. The different versions of ctz didn't change anything unfortunatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Debian/Sid/x86-64 (Intel i4750HQ processor) with `gcc version 4.9.1 (Debian 4.9.1-4)` and `valgrind-3.9.0` your test is working ok (and `valgrind` runs successfully without reporting any errors).

So I suggest you to upgrade your [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler and most importantly [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Start first by compiling `valgrind` from its [valgrind-3.9.0](http://valgrind.org/downloads/valgrind-3.9.0.tar.bz2) source code tarball (and use `aptitude build-dep valgrind` before).

BTW, your distribution version is quite old. Did you consider upgrading to Ubuntu 14.0 LTS?

If you don't have root access, consider passing  some explicit `--prefix` (e.g. `$HOME/pub/` ) to `valgrind-3.9.0/configure`

Comment: Probably more important to upgrade valgrind than gcc.

Comment: And update for valgrind did solve the problem. Updating the system might be a problem since the Hardware is already quite dated.. thank you for the help

Answer (score 4):

You need to upgrade valgrind to at least 4.8.1 or use an gcc older than v4.8.

The opcode you ran into -- `F3 0F BC` -- is the `TZCNT` opcode, introduced in BMI1, which your CPU doesn't implement. However, it is *also* `REP;BSF` (`F3` is `REP`) and older CPUs, including yours, ignore the `REP` for this opcode, and the similar `LZCNT == REP;BSR` pair. There is very little difference between `TZCNT` and `BSF` (they differ in how they handle 0).

Older `gcc` versions used `BSF` for older CPUs and `TZCNT` for newer ones, but since the opcode is relatively rare, in newer gcc versions the logic was simplified and `TZCNT` is always used, since both older and newer CPUs understand it.

Unfortunately, `valgrind` did not correctly fallback from `TZCNT` to `BSF` until v4.8.1. See [bug 295808](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=295808).

Comment: So let me get this strait. If I do a check `val != 0` bevorehand they it should still be fine?

Comment: @magu_: You need to check that `val != 0` because the gcc `__builtin_ctz` is undefined for that case (see gcc manual). But that's not the problem with valgrind. The problem is that valgrind (before v4.8.1) didn't understand that it should ignore the `REP` in `REP BSF`, so when it hits that instruction it thinks it's illegal. (The difference between `BSF` and `TZCNT` is that `TZCNT` returns 32 if its argument is 0 (in general, the bit-size of the argument), whereas the result of `BSF` is undefined. See also `__builtin_ffs`, which returns 0 for 0 and `1+ctz` for any other argument.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the elaboration